# android - why decodeFile(path) isnt working when file is saved in Camera folder on Samsung?

Tags: android, bitmap, samsung-mobile

I have

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

working properly. the only exception I'm facing now is if the photo is stored in Camera folder on a samsung device, `imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);` will not display the image.

I tried to printout the path, and I got `storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20140404_120332.jpg` which is the same path I see in gallery. What's weird about this is my code seems only not working when images are stored in `Camera` folder. Other images like `storage/extSdCard/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0327.jpg` would display the correct bitmap. What's so special about this `Camera` folder? both images are stored in sdcard but why the one store in `Camera` not working? Do I need a particular permission? or is this a bug?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you crashing? Is LogCat reporting anything?

Comment: no crash. I tried to print out the path and it is correct. `bm` is not null either

Comment: Have you tried copying `20140404_120332.jpg` to someplace else, to confirm that your problem is tied to the folder, and not the image itself?

Comment: good point. going to try it now

Comment: i think i found the reason. while trying to display the image, i got `outofmemoryexception`. i think you are right. the problem is coming from that image

Comment: the image is taking way to long to load. i dont care about the quality. i only want to display a thumbnail. is there a way to reduce the quality?

Comment: `BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();`
`options.inSampleSize = 16;`

Comment: that would do the work. thank you very much @CommonsWare